# Collections in Ruby - is there a collections class like Set but with the member access of Hash?

Tags: ruby, collections

After reading the *Collections* chapter in Peter Jones' book, *Effective Ruby*, the Set class may seem to provide an interesting alternative to Hash. Concerning the Set class, Jones relates:

> It’s a lot like its mathematical cousin, a collection of unordered unique elements with operations such as union, intersection, and subset/superset testing.

My only concern is in whether the Set class may not provide direct access to actual member objects.

Presently, I'm trying to use `Set` (or something like `Set`) to implement a naive `OptionSet` API, such that an option in the `OptionSet` may be of a type `Option` or `ValueOption`, with the latter being a subclass of `Option`. This API may need access to the objects stored in what respective collection for each `OptionSet` - whether stored in a separate Hash, Array, some other container object, or stored in the `OptionSet` via some inherited implementation e.g with `Set` as a superclass.

I'd like to use `Set` within `OptionSet`, or to simply implement `OptionSet` as a subclass of `Set`. However, if `Set` may not provide direct access to the member objects, once stored - short of iterating across every member object in the `Set`, as until finding any ostensible match (e.g. once finding any `Option` or `ValueOption` in the collection, such that the "match" would have an equivalent `Option.name`, typically a symbol) - maybe there's a more effective alternative?

I'd provide sample code, but the implementation of `OptionSet` is not presently usable. In pseudocode, I'm trying to implement `OptionSet#getopt(name)` as to return the value of any named `Option` object stored in the `OptionSet`, or false if no such option is stored.

The `#getopt` method would call `self.getoptObj(name)`, a protected method such that would need to access the named option's actual `Option` object in the collection. Except for that part of the implementation, otherwise Set might be directly suitable.

In any analogy to Scheme-like languages, the Ruby standard library might not provide an AssociativeList class, *per se*? Simply, I wonder if there's any class like `Set` -- i.e with set-theoretic methods as in `Set` -- but with the member access of `Hash`?

**Update**

I've tried to implement a `MappedSet` class, at least in pseudocode, such as to use an instance `Hash` value to store a mapping between general "Keys" and member objects. I believe that would be redundant to the international storage of `Set`, however. Maybe I should simply extend `Hash`.

Comment: It sounds like you're overthinking it. Why not just use a hash if you want a dictionary like structure? Your requirement of returning false can be done with `Hash#default`. Also I'm not sure about Set but the core classes in Ruby like Hash can be perilous to subclass since they are implemented in C and do not behave like "real" Ruby classes.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzdSxgVPhXU

Comment: Look likes you are trying to do what an hash is expecting to do. Why not just use an Hash then?

Comment: @max, @tomsoft a Hash might be more effective. I believe I'm trying to mimic some of the characteristics of a Common Lisp hash-table, albeit while trying to learn about Ruby. Once I can figure out how to provide a key function in `initialize`, that might be the thing. Meanwhile, I'll try to avoid subclassing Set or Hash - on further reading of Peter Jones' _Effective Ruby: 48 Specific Ways to Write Better Ruby_ there's an example of using a `forwardable` module and `def_delegators` to provide functionality like the `Hash` class, but with extension. TY for the advice

Comment: As a tiny note here: the `Set` class in Ruby is in fact [implemented](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/set.rb) as a wrapper around a Hash in pure Ruby. The members of the set are stored as the keys of the Hash with a value of `true`. All set operations then work on this internal Hash.

Comment: @hoger-just ah! Thanks for the pointer. I'll try to take a look at the source code, short of overoptimizing the implementation here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a hash like class you can use DelegateClass:

```
class FalsyHash < DelegateClass(Hash)
  def initialize(hash)
    super.tap { |result| result.default = false }
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):001:0> f = FalsyHash.new(a: :b)
=> {:a=>:b}
irb(main):002:0> f[:b]
=> false
irb(main):003:0> f.is_a?(Hash)
=> false
```

This is basically just a class that takes an instance of the provided class and wraps it so that method calls are forwarded. Since its not actually an instance of Hash we avoid the pitfalls that happen when core methods check if we are dealing with a hash which would occur if we used a subclass of Hash.

The same thing can be acheived with Delegator, SimpleDelegator and Forwardable - DelegateClass is just a straight forward way of wrapping classes.

You can also augment specific instances of Hash by extending them with a module:

```
module Reversable
  def reverse
    transform_values { |v| v.respond_to?(:reverse) ? v.reverse : v }
  end
end

# Guess what this returns for a cookie
{ foo: 'olleH', bar: nil, baz: 'dlrow' }.extend(Reversable)
                                        .reverse
                                        .values
                                        .compact
                                        .sort     
                                        .join(" ")
```